# Cannot get grub to boot into Win 7

Tags: grub2, windows, uefi

I've google searched heaps and tried all the options so far, but nothing seems to work. Windows 7 does not show up on the grub loader after installing Ubuntu 14.04.

I've tried editing /etc/grub.d/40_custom by adding:

```
menuentry "Windows 7 UEFI" {
    search --fs-uuid --no-floppy --set=root 5761-0BA2
    chainloader (${root})/efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
}
```

but the grub loader just says:

```
error: file `/efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi` not found
```

I ran bootinfoscript and this is my output (the EFI partition appears to be sda6):
http://pastebin.com/4rzxPTC4

I'm at a loss. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You have a GPT disk and no sign of a Windows boot loader installed on your EFI System Partition (ESP; your `/dev/sda5`), but Boot Info Script *is* reporting a BIOS-mode Windows boot loader installed on the disk's MBR. You do seem to have an EFI-mode version of GRUB on the disk. This combination makes me think that you started with an MBR disk, converted it to GPT, and installed Ubuntu in EFI mode. If I'm right about this, you won't get it to boot as it is, because Windows will boot only in EFI mode from a GPT disk, so you must first install an EFI boot loader for Windows. See [this page](https://gitorious.org/tianocore_uefi_duet_builds/pages/Windows_x64_BIOS_to_UEFI) for information on how to do this. You've already done much of what needs to be done, so you should be able to start with step 3.5 (although it refers to a backup created in step 3.1, so check it out, too).

Comment: If I had installed Ubuntu NOT in GPT mode, would that have avoided this problem? If so, how do I prevent it from installing Ubuntu using GPT?

AAAnnnd, if I were to reinstall Ubuntu without GPT while not touching windows, would that correct it?

Comment: I tried following the steps in your link but I don't really understand what I'm doing. I have no objection to reinstalling the OSes from scratch if I know how to do it correctly.

Comment: If you re-install, pick *one* boot mode (BIOS or EFI). If you pick BIOS, use MBR on the disk; if you pick EFI, use GPT on the disk. Note that the GPT/MBR choice is set down on the whole disk and applies to both OSes.

Comment: How do I tell which one I'm using? Is there a setting I need to change during installation?